# Как выделить несколько строк не выделяя при этом весь столбец в JTable Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Есть таблица JTable, нужно выделить подряд непрерывный блок ячеек, не выделяя при этом весь столбец.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выделить ячейки D,E,F в 1 строке и ячейки 0 со значением 6С во второй строке, предусмотрено ли это ? Так, как если я выделяю мышкой происходит, то что видно на скрине. При выделении с помощью функций

```
hexTable.setColumnSelectionInterval();
hexTable.setRowSelectionInterval();
```

происходит то же самое.

P.S. Мне нужно это для обработки выделенных значений, есть вариант конечно увеличивать количество столбцов динамически,чтобы все нужные значения попадали в одну строку, но это выглядит как костыль.

Comment: конечно это банально, и с JTable я не работал, но раз вы выделяете мышкой то разве нельзя зажать кнопку Ctrl при выделении?

Comment: @NewDumb Происходит то же самое

Comment: у JTable есть метод называется setSelectedModel или как-то так, в нём надо задать параметр MultySelection

ListSelectionModel lsm = jtable.getSelectionModel();
lsm.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);